# Existe diferença em se criar objetos e adicionar propriedades com a notação literal ou com `new Object` em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, objetos

Tenho uma dúvida. Fazer isto aqui:

```js
let meuCarro = new Object();
meuCarro.fabricacao = 'Ford';
meuCarro.modelo = 'Mustang';
meuCarro.ano = 1969;
console.log(meuCarro.fabricacao);
console.log(meuCarro.modelo);
console.log(meuCarro.ano);
```

É a mesma coisa de fazer isto?

```js
let meuCarro = { 
    fabricacao: 'Ford',
    modelo: 'Mustang',
    ano: 1969,
}
console.log(meuCarro.fabricacao);
console.log(meuCarro.modelo);
console.log(meuCarro.ano);
```

Há alguma diferença entre usar `{}` e `new Object` para criar objetos em JavaScript?

Comment: Sim, mas da segunda forma, na chave fabricacao vc está atribuido um array em vez de um string. recomendo usar a segunda forma, é mais sucinto, apesar de não existir um porque não fazer da primeira forma

Answer (score 7):

Não há diferença em relação à **construção** do objeto, mas a semântica de como as propriedades são adicionadas é diferente.

Objetos literais em JavaScript são açúcar sintático para construção de objetos `Object`.

Portanto, fazer:

```
const obj = new Object();
```

É exatamente a mesma coisa que isto:

```
const obj = {};
```

Nesse sentido, a diferença é meramente sintática. E claro, você já pode *definir* as propriedades diretamente na notação literal.

---

Todavia há diferença ao se adicionar as propriedades no objeto (embora isso raramente faça diferença significante).

Ao adicionar as propriedades diretamente no objeto literal, utiliza-se a mesma semântica da função `Object.defineProperty` – isto é, semântica de **definição de propriedades**. Ao se definir uma propriedade, nenhum *setter* será ativado.

Veja:

```js
// Modificarei o protótipo para demonstrar que nenhum setter é invocado.
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'foo', {
  set: function(val) {
    console.log(`Called setter 'foo' with value '${val}'.`);
  }
});

const myObj = {
  foo: 'Bar' // Nenhuma mensagem será impressa ao se definir esta propriedade.
};
```

Contudo, ao se utilizar o operador de atribuição (`=`), a semântica de ***assignment*** ativa os *setters*, se existirem. Veja:

```js
// Modificarei o protótipo para demonstrar que o setter é invocado
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'foo', {
  set: function(val) {
    console.log(`Called setter 'foo' with value '${val}'.`);
  }
});

const myObj = {};
myObj.foo = 'Bar'; // Uma mensagem será impressa ao se setar esta propriedade.
```

Mas repare que, nesse ponto, a diferença nem mais se trata sobre a forma literal ou `new Object`. A diferença, nesse sentido, dá-se pela forma como as propriedades são adicionadas.

Resumindo, em JavaScript, a semântica de definição de propriedades é diferente da semântica de atribuição de propriedades.

Answer (score -2):

Sim, são equivalentes. Os dois métodos estão declarando o objeto e definindo suas propriedades, mas, na segunda maneira, você declarou `fabricacao` como um array, e não como string.

Fazer da segunda forma é mais recomendado, deixa seu código mais limpo e mais fácil de entender.